# How to use Flock notification plugin as a Post-build Action on a pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins and flock for notifying build statuses to flock. On a freestyle project, it is easy as we can add flock-notification plugin as a post-build action. However, on pipelines there is no option for adding a post-build job. I see there is a way to adding post-action to pipeline scripts but the problem with this is there is no documentation for using flock notification plugin on a pipeline. I don't want to create manual post requests to this since I think its a meaningless effort. Is there anyone on a similar situation found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the same problem. I advanced a bit although could not receive a notification on the flock but able to execute the script successfully.
There is a DSL method from the 'Flock Notification' plugin named **flockNotify**. Use this method inside the post block in the pipeline script. This method accepts certain params which are -

*flockNotify(String webhookUrl, boolean notifyOnStart, boolean notifyOnSuccess, boolean notifyOnUnstable, boolean notifyOnAborted, boolean notifyOnFailure, boolean notifyOnNotBuilt, boolean notifyOnRegression, boolean notifyOnBackToNormal)*

I found this at [flock plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/flock-plugin). If able to succeed please do let know.